# Modify upstart to provide more debugging information but can't configure upstart

Tags: upstart

On an embedded ARM device, Linux 3.12.8 is slow to start in some configurations.  From the messages elicited there is clearly something that `upstart` is waiting for.  However, it is very difficult to find out what since the system has not started, and logging in to issue `initctl` to find out what it is doing is not available.

Building it looks like it should be simple, but `./configure` does not work.  The last bit it shows is:

```
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.22... yes
checking for nih-dbus-tool... no
checking for NIH... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libnih >= 1.0.2) were not met:

No package 'libnih' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables NIH_CFLAGS
and NIH_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I have searched all over the Ubuntu repositories for `nih`, `libnih`, and even `NIH`.  I am trying to do this on x86-64 Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with kernel 3.10.5 to make it easier to succeed for the moment.   What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NIH Utility Library in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/libnih)

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install libnih1
```

Development package is named *libnih-dev* You might also need *libnih-dbus1* and *libnih-dbus-dev* packages.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I do `$ sudo apt-get install libnih-dev` and got to the next hurdle:  `No package 'libnih-dbus' found`.  I tried to install `libnih-dbus`, but it doesn't know about any such package.

Comment: The above was solved with installing `libnih-dbus-dev`.  The hurdle after that is `No package 'dbus-1' found`.`

Comment: And the above was resolved with `sudo apt-get install libdbus-1`.

Comment: Try apt-rdepends to get the full list of dependencies. See this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21379/how-do-i-find-the-build-dependencies-of-a-package) for details.